# Routing Silex in a sub directory of DocumentRoot

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes, apache2

I have a setup a like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName some.project
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/projects/some/public"
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I can access my Silex page via `http://some.project/`.

What I want to do is to add an administration page lying under my public folder:

```
/var/www/projects/some/public/admin
```

For that I added a `.htaccess` file, [as mentioned in the docs](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html) to the created admin directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /var/www/projects/some/public/admin
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now if I call `http://some.project/admin/` it works, but any other route lying under `/admin/` returns a 404 error page (e.g. `http://some.project/admin/setting`).

The Silex project is nothing spectacular, just a few routes for testing.
`mod_rewrite` is enabled of course

Can any one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteBase` is relative from `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. Try this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /admin/

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```